# What is the fastest when it comes to reading in Firebase real time database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, database-performance

In my quest to understand Firebase Realtime Database I want to know what is the fastest when it comes to reading. I don´t know if asking the question like this is not suitable for Firebase, but anyway I have to start somewhere right.

In what way is this list of nods or an array och keys faster and why. Is the speed dependent on how the question is asked, if so how to ask the question to get speed? This question is about speed only and reading only.

Is the speed dependent on the length of the key or if the key is a Pushed time stamp. Is the speed dependent on the nr of keys?

(this is not a broad question and please don´t downvote)

Firebase data structure 1-billions of keys: - no comment

```
"Stars_in_the_sky": {
  "star_1": "-wjkhwe872hjwekj",
  "star_2": "-sds768787sada6s",
  "star_3": "-sd9876sad8asd7d",
  ...,
  ...,
  "star_127169118922": "-334d78sddisd798sd98sds9d8sds"
}
```

Firebase data structure 1-billions of keys: - using push ids

```
"Stars_in_the_sky": {
  "-Kjkhwe872hjwekj": {
    "name" : "star_1"
  },
  "-Kds768787sada6s": {
    "name" : "star_2"
  },
  "-Kd9876sad8asd7d": {
    "name" : "star_3"
  },
  ...,
  ...,
  "-K334d78sddisd798sd98sds9d8sds": {
    "name" : "star_127169118922"
  },
}
```

Firebase data structure 1-billions of keys - using custom keys

```
"Stars_in_the_sky": {
  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee": {
    "name" : "star_1"
  },
  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff": {
    "name" : "star_2"
  },
  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff-ggg": {
    "name" : "star_3"
  },
  ...,
  ...,
  "aaa-bbb-ccc-ddd-eee-fff-ggg-hhh..........................": {
    "name" : "star_127169118922"
  },
}
```

Comment: There is no "fastest way to load data" from anything. It depends on the exact query that you execute. Unless you have a specific query, this is too broad.

Comment: That said: in general the most important factor that determines the loading speed that you as a developer can control is the size of the data that you download. To get the data faster, load less data. Instead of optimizing the size of each item, you'll often get greater benefits faster by downloading fewer items.

Comment: Grate to know thanks